# HP Elitebook 8530p's CPU Increases to 100% when plugged In

Tags: laptop, cpu, battery

I apologize if this post is too long or doesn't describe the issue properly. I have absolutely no idea why it is doing this, apparently it is a problem with HP computers or a particular strand of them as I've seen others post about similar problems with their HPs. Essentially what happens is whenever I plug a charger into this Elitebook it slows down considerably, to the point of which pages become unresponsive and nothing will adequately load. It even happens when nothing besides the laptop's background processes are running. I've also noticed that it doesn't charge nearly as fast, it mostly keeps the laptop stable (although it does charge it- I plugged it in overnight and it went from 0% to 51%). This laptop was recently reformatted and uses Windows-7, I've only had it for a day, although it was pre-owned. It's been doing this the entire time I've owned it.

After looking on the task manager, I realized the CPU was being used 100%. This confused me, as prior to plugging in the charger it generally remained below 50%. Non-intensive process like task manager went from taking 4% or 5% to 40% or 50%. After a while, or seemingly when I move around the charger, the amount of used CPU will go down, but only to a level that makes the laptop usable, not to the level that it is on battery. It also seems to make it charge a lot faster.

I've tried a variety of things to fix this. Because my uncle had recently reformatted this laptop (it used to be his old one) I doubted this was a software problem. I tried using a different charger (I have a 90W and a 120W one), which changed nothing. I've tried using the laptop while the battery is out, which also didn't help. Unless there is an issue with the CPU, I have no idea what could cause this on the hardware end.

So I also tried software fixes. I went into the power options and made the options for the laptop when plugged in the same as unplugged, which did nothing obvious regarding the CPU. I tried going into the Task Scheduler and making it so that no extra processes begin running when the laptop gets plugged in which also had no notable effect. I even tried a system restore, on the off-chance that something I did in the day of owning the laptop messed it up somehow, which of course changed nothing.

I am completely at wits end when it comes to solving this problem. I recall reading something about an extra central pin in a HP charger and if the laptop is receiving weak voltage from that secondary pin it reduces the CPU's power to conserve energy, but I don't exactly recall and I can't find this article again. I don't have much if any technical expertise, especially at the hardware end. Hopefully someone can help me resolve this problem, otherwise I have a near useless laptop. Thank you.

EDIT:
I somehow stupidly forgot to mention that I started up the computer in safe mode and the problem was resolved which is what prompted me to check for software fixes in the first place, but for obvious reasons I can't continually use safe mode. Also, I've used several different wall outlets, although all in the same house.

Answer (score 0):

As you said above, this is most probably not a software problem. What comes to my mind right now is only something in the hardware side that could trigger this. 
I would recommend trying with a different charger (with the same parameters with the original), and if it is still happening, the problem might be in the DC power jack also. If that is the case you might need to check if there is a problem in the DC power jack connection pins. If there is no problem with the power cord or DC power jack, then please, try if you can to replace the cpu (if just for testing), switching position of RAM modules, or removing one at a time (assuming you have two or more). Also, testing out all other laptop parts would be great if the problem is still there. If even after checking all parts, and the problem still persists, the last thing could be the motherboard itself. Sometimes faulty motherboards are unable to supply the right amount of electricity to each part.

Another additional option is to check if you can disable HAL.dll in the bios options:
http://bit.ly/1vb0PUX 
http://youtu.be/jvMkt9fkHCI 
I said an additional option, since as you tried everything out, this might not be a software problem.

Lastly, it would be good to try out with another OS. You can find a lot of linux based os for free. This might seem not something related to the problem, but sometimes it could be related. If the problem doesn't happen with that other system (you can try ubuntu, fedora, elementary os, xubuntu etc.), please try to disable Hal.dll
If nothing works out, please comment again, to see if there is any other option left.
I hope this helped!